# Difference between !ls -aF vs !ls -af

Tags: ls

I have a basic question about defference between "ls -aF" and "ls -af .".

From these two commands, what would be different?

Based on my understand,
"ls -aF" it will show the all files and directory. Also, All directory will be shown with "/" and files will show as it looks.
"ls -af . " it will show the all files and directory. Unlike "ls -aF", all directory will show as it is, but all files will show with bullet points.

Lastly, does it has differences between upper case F and lower case f ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Sunpil! However, I don't see how any of this relates to python or programming in general...

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I was working on Jupyter and the file that I was working on was .ipynb so I thought it might has a relationship with Python.

Comment: you might want to use `man ls` and read the man page for ls - it should tell you what the options do - or look online f,e,. here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ls.1posix.html (for ubuntu). As the question is not programming related its offtopic here, might fit at superuser BUT you can easily research it yourself so shouldnt need to ask over there.

Comment: `ls` works the same way no matter whether you call it from Jupyter -- and that way is specific to your operating system vendor, not to Python or bash itself. As Patrick says above, `man ls` will have the documentation that's correct for your specific OS. Also, [unix.se] is a better fit than Stack Overflow for general-purpose UNIX questions; likewise, [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Stack Overflow is limited to questions that are "unique to software development".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, let's take it by parts.

1. The command `ls` is used to list files, and `-af .` or `-aF` are basically arguments.
2. That said, what is the difference between `-af` and `-aF`. Let me show a really handy tool for that, [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com). This may be handy when you need some informations about the manpages and arguments of some cammands. In this particular case, taking from the manpage from `ls`, that cam be accessed by typing `man ls` in the terminal:

- `-a, --all`  : do not ignore entries starting with `.`. What are those you ask? Files starting with a `.`in Linux systems are "hidden", so they would not show up for you in a file manager or some command line utilities.
- `-f`: do not sort, enable -aU, disable -ls --color. That's a lot to take in, but basically this means that the contents will be listed in order, and disable the coloring for the output.
- `-F, --classify`: append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries. Just like you said, this will put at the end of the entry an identifier related to the entry type: `/`is for directories, while `@`is for symbolic links and so on

3. With this knowledge, what is the difference between both commands? Let's first remember the syntax from the manpage for `ls`:

```sh
ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

So, in your case:

1. `ls`is the command
2. `-af` or `-aF` are the `OPTIONS`;
3. `.` or nothing would be the `FILE`. In linux `.` represents current directory, while `..`represents the parent directory, `~` is the home directory, and many more you can look up.

So when you are running `ls -af .` you are asking to the system "Hey, list me the files in the current directory, including the hidden ones, in the order they exist in the directory". While when running `ls -aF .` you are saying "System, list me all files in the current directory, including the hidden ones, showing me the type of entry by appending a 'symbol' at the end of entry when needed".

I hope this helps, and I also advise you to look the manpages for any command you have doubts about it by using `man command` where command is the command you are trying to get information about. Most Linux utilities have one, and many Thrid party apps also do. Explain shell is a good thing, and as an example, here is the [manpage online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/ls.1.html) for `ls`.

Comment: On a quick note, if you don't pass anything for ls it will assume the current directory.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help and describe all information for me!!